# Row span in UI Grid Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to divide a Row into two ie. Row Span in Angular JS UI Grid. I am not able to find how to do this.I need different color schemes for rows within the rows of the UI grid. Can anyone please help me with this and give me some related fiddle or plunker to refer. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: do you have any code yet?

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/fsJdENoN1ll4FUGsPzts/ This is the Link i got for column Span . Similarly i need it for Row span.

Answer (score 0):

I have a RowSpan hack, suitable for my need, not necessarily suitable for every case: I use `position:absolute` on the top row's cell and `display:none` on the spanned rows' cells. See http://plnkr.co/edit/TiQFJnyOvVECOH2RL4ha

Everything is in the **ng-style** in the cell template, which uses a `spanCompany` attribute to know the number of rows to override. We have to calculate the `height` and `width` since we are `position:absolute`. This also means the width has to be expressed in `px`, not %.

**ng-style extract:**

```
ng-style="{ 
  height:21*row.entity.spanCompany+'px',
  width:col.width+'px',
  position:'absolute',
  display:row.entity.spanCompany==0?'none':'block'
}"
```

**Full code:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.data = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo has a rather long company name that might need to be displayed in a tooltip",
        "spanCompany":2,
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "spanCompany":0,
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "spanCompany":1,
        "employed": false
    }
  ];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'firstName', width: '20%' },
      { name: 'lastName', width: '20%' },
      { name: 'company', width: '200',
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents wrap" title="TOOLTIP" ng-style="{ height:21*row.entity.spanCompany + \'px\', width:col.width+\'px\', position:\'absolute\', display:row.entity.spanCompany==0?\'none\':\'block\', borderStyle:\'dotted\', borderWidth:\'1px\'}" >{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>'
      },
      { name: 'employed', width: '30%' }
    ],
    data: 'data',
    rowHeight: 21

  };
}]);
```